# Mongodb not taking coordinates (legacy coordinate pairs error)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I'm doing a bulk insert of records into a Mongoose schema with GeoJSON coordinates.

```
var LocationObject = new Schema({
  type:{type:String, required: true, enum: "Point", default: "Point"},
  coordinates: {type:[Number], default: [0,0]}
});
LocationObject.index({location: '2dsphere'});
var Location = new Schema({
  name: String,
  loc: [LocationObject]
});
```

My insert looks fairly simple. This is from one of the records, the first one, that errors out:

```
{
  name: "My location name",
  loc: [{ type: "Point", coordinates: [39.75796, -86.14794000000001]}, {}]
}
```

The actual error message being:

`geo values must be 'legacy coordinate pairs' for 2d indexes`

There's a little empty object in there that might be doing something I suppose, but I'm unsure where it's coming from or what impact it's actually having. Anyone seeing anything particularly wrong with this code?

Comment: `LocationObject.index({location: '2dsphere'});` looks as if you create an index on a field `location` which appears nowhere in your documents. Also, `2dsphere` and `2d` indexes are different. Is there maybe a 2d index on the collection which comes from some earlier experiments? You can check it in the mongo shell with `db.collection.getIndexes()`.

Comment: @Philipp This appears to have at least moved me in the right direction... haven't gotten it working yet, but both observations appear accurate.

Comment: @Philipp Now I'm getting a `E11000 duplicate key error index: test.latlongs.$_id_ dup key: {: ObjectId(\'asdlfkjasdflkjasdflkjasdlfkj\') }` after about 80 records. I'm allowing mongoose/mongo to create the _id so I'm not sure how that's happening. Not seeing with any other collection...

Comment: @Philipp Tried dropping the entire DB and starting over (several times), no improvement. Also tried `LocationObject.index({coordinates: '2dsphere'}, {unique:false})` just in case but doesn't appear to have any effect.